# Font size based on device width

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

How should we set the font size based on device width so that mobile site renders fine on all width devices. Am using jquery mobile. Does it take care of this.

Comment: I'm not sure you *should* set font size based on device width. Are you going to resize type, for instance, when a person rotates their phone from portrait to landscape?

Comment: We recently relaunched our site as a responsive site and are using 16px as the base font size. Works great everywhere.

Comment: @media queries in the CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

Viewport. 
Writeup by David Storey: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Ex:

```css
#box{
  background-color:black;
  width: 100vh;
}


h1.rad {
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
color: #999;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
font-size:  3.14159vw;
line-height: 6.66vh;
font-weight: 100;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
<h1 class="rad">
  Viewport sizing.<br>So rad.
  </h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html { font-size: 62.5%; }
body { font-size: 1em;}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
    html { font-size: 70%; }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    html { font-size: 80%; }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
    html { font-size: 120%; }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    html { font-size: 200%; }
}

```
Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/pLyjt/
```